# How to override Drupal's default theme_table() function?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-theming

How do I override the theme_table() function of the Drupal core in my theme? I just wrote another function named theme_table() in my template.php file, but the default theme_table() is still in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your template.php file isn't being read, because having two functions with the same name should trigger an error. Try renaming your theme_table() function to *THEMENAME*_table() (where *THEMENAME* is the name of your theme) or to phptemplate_table().

If that still doesn't work, [try clearing your theme cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176).

Comment: Thanks, renaming the function to THEMENAME_table() worked. It actually showed an error when I first (before asking the question) added a function named theme_table() in my template.php. Then I renamed the function to THEMENAME_theme_table() which solved the ERROR, but didn't have any effect. Now I renamed the function to THEMENAME_table() and it works as it should. Thanks :)